# Animation lag while loading data

Tags: android, animation, asynchronous, lag

I am loading some data into a `LinearLayout`. I get this data from a network request or from the local storage. This happens in `onCreate`. At the same time in `onCreate` after I started the request, I start an animation. This animation lags and is hardly visible because of the 1fps ^^. My question is if somebody knows how to prevent it and if it is caused by:

- loading the data into the `LinearLayout` (because 2 actions in the UI?)
- the network request (is asynchronous so it shouldn't be the problem)